# variable in jquery giving Uncaught ReferenceError when defined without var

Tags: javascript, jquery

A piece of code from my javascript file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    gsdk.init();
});

// Note: No var in the prefix of gsdk and it is also declared only here
gsdk = {
    init : some function...
}
```

When I add this javascript file in html page and run, it gives

`Uncaught ReferenceError: gsdk is not defined(…)`

Comment: Have you tried moving `gsdk = {}` in front of `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: sorry `);` is there I missed it...

Comment: You are missing the Jquery Plugin.

Comment: moving `gsdk = {}` any different if both the function and variable are in the global execution context

Comment: This `<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>` is there in html file before adding my javascript file

Comment: @akar: Yes, it's different, if the `ready` callback is called synchronously (which it is sometimes).

Comment: @JigneshRawal: The quoted error doesn't in any way suggest jQuery isn't loaded on the page.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes it does not say that in any way.But only way to check this is comment out the line saying gsdk.init() under the document ready.

Answer (score 4):

That code is relying on [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html)¹, where assigning to an undeclared identifier creates a global variable.

To get the error you've described, the `ready` "event" would have to have *already* fired before your code is run, because jQuery's `ready` feature is chaotic: If the page is already ready, it calls its callback synchronously; if not, it calls it asynchronously.

If it were calling the callback asynchronously, you wouldn't be getting an error, because the code assigning to `gsdk` would have run *before* the code in the callback, creating the global and giving it its value.

In any case, the fix is:

1. Declare `gsdk`, don't rely on the horror of implicit globals, and
2. Move the initialization of it *above* your `ready` code, so that if your `ready` callback is called synchronously, `gsdk` is initialized and ready for use.

E.g.:

```
// 1. Declare the variable, don't rely on The Horror of Implicit Globals.
// 2. Make certain it has its value before setting up your `ready` callback, since
//    apparently you're doing this when the page is already ready.
var gsdk = {
    init : some function...
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    gsdk.init();
});
```

---

¹ *(That's a post on my anemic little blog.)*

Comment: As @Justinas suggested when I placed var prefix to gsdk and moved it before the document ready call its fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax error .It should work

Though gsdk is a global variable here ..Not declaring with var should not a problem,but it would create a variable on the global object i.e., window.gsdk/gsdk is same here and even you are declaring gsdk it after invocation it does not throw error because variables are hoisted 
your code is similar to this below

```
var gsdk;
$(document).ready(function(){
    gsdk.init();
});

gsdk = {
    init : function(){
       alert("hi");
     }
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    gsdk.init();
});

gsdk = {
    init : function(){
       alert("hi");
     }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ya but when I check my window object a `gsdk` parameter is there but it is undefined

Comment: did you check it as window.gsdk

Comment: @akar: That's because (as I said in my answer), your `ready` callback is getting called synchronously. If you just make the change above, `gsdk` will be declared but will have the value `undefined`.